# Resources in public directory not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, directory-structure

I have been using Node and Angular for quite a while now, but never really put much thought or effort into the back-end structure. I am trying to split up the client and server and basically make a skeleton I can use for most of my applications. Everything else has gone well and smooth up until this point. Here is what my directory structure looks like:

[image: App directory structure]

In app.js, I use this line to set the static assets folder: `app.use(express.static(config.server.distFolder));`

which simply points to `/client/dist`. Now all of this works fine, it loads index.html and any CSS/JS assets linked to in the html file. The only thing not being loaded is the views folder inside the angular folder as pictured below.

[image: Console inspector - sources]

Since the Angular router can't find the view (because it's not loaded), it defaults to loading `index.html` again causing the page to just be duplicated inside the `ng-view` directive.

I presume this is because it isn't being used/called/loaded in at all in the `index.html` file. How do I get this folder to be included into the static assets? In other code I look it it just seems to be there. I must be missing something. My original understanding of setting the static directory was everything in that directory became available to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it was a stupidly simple fix. Angular was looking for the view in `/views` when it should be `/angular/views`. Overlooked the root folder.

All I did was change this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/index.html'
    });
```

to this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'angular/views/index.html'
    });
```